# Ionic 3 Adding Multiple Tab Navigations on a single tab or page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic v3 and need to implement a page where i have few tabs on bottom of the home screen to navigate to all other sections of the application. Implemented the same by starting ionic `tabs` template in starting using `ionic start exapp tabs` with multiple tabs available in the footer of the application, but now in one tab selected navigate to I need to implement two tabs on the top just after the toolbar. Applicable only for that page but am unable to do so. refereed to [Ionic tabs documentation link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/)  but unable to resolve the issue.

For better explanation of the question we can consider the example below where I need the nested option to come only on the option tab click.

[image]

Comment: Please re-produce your problem at stackblitz.com

Comment: Take a look at another component called `segment`. You can see if this is more suitable instead of having nested `tabs`.